# Angular object persistence issue

Tags: json, angular8, ros

I am writing an Angular application which will serve frontend for controlling a robot. The robot has a application installed on it which sends back a json object in response to a connection attempt. The json object is the resource via which commands are issued to the robot.

In my application, I can use the json object successfully to get the robot to respond to my commands. However, I want to persist the json object so I can use it application wide so I save it to storage , using the following code:

```
connection() {
    return this.storage.get('ros-connection-object');
}

connect(address: string, port: number) {
    console.log('ROS-SERVICE_CONNECT!');
    
    this.ros = new rosLib.Ros({
        url : 'ws://' + address + ':' + port
    });
    console.log(this.ros);

    this.storage.set('ros-connection-object', this.ros);
    this.storage.set('ros-connection-address', address);
    this.storage.set('ros-connection-port', port);

    this.router.navigate(['/'], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

My problems, begin when I retrieve the object and use it to issue commands. I get the following error:

```
core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: that.ros.callOnConnection is not a function
    at Topic.callForSubscribeAndAdvertise (Topic.js:59)
    at Topic.push../node_modules/roslib/src/core/Topic.js.Topic.advertise (Topic.js:150)
    at Topic.push../node_modules/roslib/src/core/Topic.js.Topic.publish (Topic.js:194)
    at AppComponent.test (app.component.ts:72)
    at AppComponent_Template_button_click_1_listener (app.component.html:3)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21693)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:21735)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:934)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41264)
```

I attached a screenshot below showing both objects, the first object is the original connection json object which works and below it is the same object save to and retrieved from storage:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's unfortunately not how storage in Angular works. You can store JSON Data but it does not store the corresponding methods.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/storage

> It provides an easy way to store key/value pairs and JSON objects.

I think there are some issues with the approach too because `Roslibjs` is relying on it's underlying websocket to be alive.

However, if you serialize and recover the data there's no telling if the WS has emitted events that weren't picked up in the meantime. for eg. the robot or the ROSBridge closing the socket

---

Persisting it to use it application wide may not require you saving it to storage.

I would recommend

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#angular-dependency-injection

which is a method for exposing services that all components require